# How can I use ps and pwdx both together?

Tags: bash, ps

I have a `Top` command that I use to see what's going on in my server:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd:50,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head 20
```

Basically it's using `ps` and removes a bunch of columns.

For each process id I can use `pwdx` to see where is the source directory.

However, I'm stuck at joining the `pwdx` to the output of the command above to add it as a column.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 9):

So weird that procps would include a `ps` and `pwdx` commands and not provide a `ps -o cwd`.

On Linux (your `ps` command invocation is already Linux (procps)-specific anyway), getting the `c`urrent `w`orking `d`irectory of a process is just a matter of doing a `readlink("/proc/<pid>/cwd")`, so you could just do:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd:50,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem |
  perl -lane 'print "$_ " . ($. == 1 ? "CWD" : readlink("/proc/$F[0]/cwd"));
              exit if $. == 20'
```

Without the need for `pwdx` (or `head`).

Comment: I wondered about `-o cwd` too...

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to use AWK to extract each pid, and run `pwdx` on that, merging the output:

```bash
ps -eo pid,cmd:50,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -n 20 |
awk 'NR == 1 { print $0 " CWD" };
     NR > 1 {
       printf "%s", $0;
       cmd = "exec pwdx " $1 " 2>&1"
       cmd | getline
       close(cmd)
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
         printf " %s", $i;
       printf "\n"
     }'
```

This adds a “CWD” header to the first line, and on all subsequent lines:

- outputs the current line (the output from `ps`);
- runs `pwdx` on the current pid, and reads the output (including errors) into `$0`;
- outputs all fields after the first (which repeats the pid);
- ends the line.

Including errors in the parsed output of `pwdx` ensures that they don’t mess up the overall output, and are shown instead of the current directory for the corresponding process (typically, “Permission denied” for processes whose information can’t be read by the current user).

This isn’t particularly efficient, spawning a shell and `pwdx` per process; but since there are only at most 19 processes to look at, it shouldn’t be noticeable. [Stéphane Chazelas’ Perl-based answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/760740/86440) is much more efficient (and shorter).

Comment: Note that it assumes the path of the current working directories don't contain newline characters as `cmd | getline` only takes gets the first line of the output of the command. That also turns sequence of blanks in the cwds to one space (but then again, for the cmd field, `ps`  also does its own mangling).